# Cannot open selenium webdriver when file path is declared as variable

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to set file path into variable and then open selenium webdriver. 
Files are located by user so i need this value as variable, instead of raw paste file path.

When i use this:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = 
FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\...\Geckodriver);

service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
```

Everything is fine, but when i replace paths with variables its not working anymore.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null))
        {
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isos = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("firefoxpath.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, iso))
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(isos))
                    {
                        fpath = sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }


        using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null))
        {
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isos = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("gecopath.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, iso))
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(isos))
                    {
                        gpath = sr.ReadLine();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    string fpath;
    string gpath;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string elo;
        string byebye;
        elo = "@\"xd\"".Replace("xd", gpath);
        byebye = "@\"xd\"".Replace("xd", fpath);
        FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(elo);
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = byebye;
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor; 



        }
}
```

}

Comment: Start using NuGet to get and install Selenium and the drivers and you can get rid of all this path nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using Selenium with C#, And if your project contains NuGet Package Manager Dependency, There is no need to define any path for Chrome/Firefox/Edge in Script OR System  Environment.

Driver utility will call internally.

For firefox : Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver in NuGet Package Manager